# Which type of bread is good for health?

Tags: diet, carbohydrates, grains

There are many types of breads that are available in market like milk bread, brown bread etc. Which bread I should eat that can be more good for my health.

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? It's unlikely that you will get a conclusive answer since this is constantly debated. People will have different opinions on what type of bread is healthy, and some will say that no bread at all is healthy. I'm not sure you'll be any better off than that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Whole grain bread with the most fiber and protien, with the shortest ingredients list with no preservatives, colors, sugar, would be best.

Fiber and protein help you feel full longer and can help you cut down on additional junk snacking.

Source:
http://www.webmd.com/diet/video/truth-about-bread

Comment: Says who? We like to see answers here backed up with more than your opinion.

Comment: See the Community Policy: Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: Added source and link

Comment: Thank you for including the source. This is the beginning of a very good answer. It would be great to explain *why* most Fiber is good for yourself. I think preservatives are quite obvious, but what is the difference between whole grain bread and white bread? If you could explain this, your answer would be really great and helpful!

Comment: Added explanatory comment

Answer (score 0):

If you buy bread from a shop it is likely to be commercial flour which is processed. Buy organic flour and make your own that way you know it is least likely to be contaminated.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].